# target and display an object of list control in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

i have made a list control. i want to display the name of the objects in it in a text control box

the code i am using here is

```
public function add(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
        var str:String;
        str = mylistcontrol.dataProvider.getItemAt(0).toString();
        mytextarea.text += str+ "has been added";
        mytextarea.text += "\n";
        }
```

The problem with this code is i am using index value of 0. however i want to display the name of object on which i have clicked or which is highlighted.

any ideas and thoughts?

Comment: how about mylistcontrol.selectedItem? But this isn't the right way to do this. I would use mylistcontrol change event to get user selection from the list.

Comment: Adobe's docs are pretty good. Maybe you should check it. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_2.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7fff.html have all the answers that you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say the name of the object do you mean the name of the ItemRenderer?

If that's the case one method you could use involves creating a custom event and a custom item renderer...

Create a custom ItemRenderer when clicked dispatch your CustomEvent which would a have a `data` property into which you can put anything you like.